# How to add Apache 2.0 License to heavily modified work

Tags: apache-2.0

I am creating a c++ file based on Android java source code.  The file is completely renamed and a lot of the code is gutted, but the basic algorithms and some function names will likely stay the same.

How should I add the android apache 2.0 license to my c++ file?  Do I need to redirect people to the original work somehow, or not?  Do I just copy the original license from the top of the java file as is and that's it?

Comment: What is the license of the original?

Comment: Related: [If I translate/port a repository from one programming language to another, do I need to use the license file (Github) from that original project?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/6699/if-i-translate-port-a-repository-from-one-programming-language-to-another-do-i)

Comment: @Brandin - The original file is https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_packages_apps_Trebuchet/blob/cm-14.1/src/com/android/launcher3/CellLayout.java