# What to keep in BSD License when porting package to another language

Tags: licensing, github, bsd, porting

I'd like to create a package based on an existing library written in a different language. The package will be a simple translation to the another language.

The existing project is licensed under the [BSD 2-Clause "Simplified" License](https://opensource.org/licenses/BSD-2-Clause) and is open-sourced on GitHub. I'd like to license my package with [The 3-Clause BSD License](https://opensource.org/licenses/BSD-3-Clause) and I'd like to publish it on GitHub and to the package manager.

What should I include in the license so that everything is fine with the law?

Comment: See [If I translate/port a repository from one programming language to another, do I need to use the license file (Github) from that original project?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/6699/if-i-translate-port-a-repository-from-one-programming-language-to-another-do-i)

Comment: Your License can be whatever you want it to be, however you should include the other License text (BSD 2-Cla...) as you found it and say in your license that works that include your work cannot violate the bounds set by the included License(s).

Answer (score 1):

Translating to another language is definitively creating a derivative work. You must keep the original notices in that case. Common courtesy dictates linking to the upstream project, perhaps notifying then of the translation; include/mention any tools used in the translation so anybody can update for new upstream versions.